# python の並列タスク間でバリア同期をとりつつ処理を再開したい

Tags: python

CPUバインドな並列タスクがあって途中でバリア同期？をとって集計タスクを追加してから処理を再開したいです

```
|   |   |
A1  B1  C1
↓   ↓   ↓
+---+---+---+ バリア同期
|   |   |   |
A2  B2  C2  M2
↓   ↓   ↓   
+---+---+---+ バリア同期
|　　　　　　|   |   |
A3  B3  C3  M3
```

正確には
A1 で作ったデータを A2
B1 で作ったデータを B2
C1 で作ったデータを C2
で使って続きを続行しつつ
A1 B1 C1 が全部おわった段階で別の集計タスクをさらに追加したいだけなので
A2 B2 C2 は他の終了を待つ必要はないですが
A B C のタスク粒度に差がないので楽に実現できるならちょっとぐらい待ってもかまわないです

---

マルチスレッドなら共有変数が使えるのでセマフォを使うなりいくらでもやりようがあるんですが
python のスレッドは OS ネイティブのものではなく
イベントループで実現されていてCPUを複数使ってくれないみたいです

プロセスなら複数のCPUにバインドされるみたいですが
メモリ空間が別になってしまうので最初と最後の args で渡す以外に
途中で情報共有する方法がわかりません

サブプロセスの終了＋メインプロセスの JOIN で終了を待つことはできますが
プロセスを exit してしまうと A2 を新しく作っても A1 とメモリ空間を共有してないので A1 のデータを使うことができません

もちろんファイルシステムやデータベース等外部サービスにカウンタをもっておいて
各プロセスでカウンタをインクリメントして
M のタスクでカウンタを見張り続けるみたいなことをすればできそうですが
システムが複雑になってしまうので軽く同期を実現するいい方法はありませんか？

---

そもそも python のスレッドで複数のCPUを使う方法があれば教えていただけると助かります

Answer (score 2):

Pythonでのマルチプロセスはいくつかあり, 標準のものでは以下のがあるようです

- [multiprocessing --- プロセスベースの並列処理](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/multiprocessing.html)
- [concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor)

(前者の) `multiprocessing` では, キュー (Queue), パイプ (Pipe), Lock, Shared memory が利用でき, また以下の記述も見られます

```
マネージャーオブジェクトを使用して同期プリミティブを作成できることも覚えておいてください。
詳細は マネージャー を参照してください。
```

---

##### Threadについて

Python … CPython でのスレッドは OSのスレッドで複数 CPUで動作可能です。GILがあるので Pythonの処理は同時に走らないけど, たとえば NumPy による演算と Python そのものとかなら走るはず。

(Threadについての追記)
[threading.get_native_id()](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/threading.html#threading.get_native_id) には次のように記されています。(Thread内で取得すれば OS-native Thread ID が別々であることが判る)

```
Return the native integral Thread ID of the current thread assigned by the kernel.
```

(ちなみにプロセス IDは `os.getpid()` で取得可能)

通常の処理を Threadにするとオーバーヘッドがかかり微妙に遅くなるところ,
NumPyの処理がある分, Thread側が微妙に速くなるケース (colabにて動作確認)
([primesfrom2to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068372/fastest-way-to-list-all-primes-below-n) は SO から)

```py
import concurrent.futures
import numpy as np

def primesfrom2to(n):
    """ Input n>=6, Returns a array of primes, 2 <= p < n """
    sieve = np.ones(n//3 + (n%6==2), dtype=bool)
    for i in range(1,int(n**0.5)//3+1):
        if sieve[i]:
            k=3*i+1|1
            sieve[       k*k//3     ::2*k] = False
            sieve[k*(k-2*(i&1)+4)//3::2*k] = False
    return np.r_[2,3,((3*np.nonzero(sieve)[0][1:]+1)|1)]

def primesum(num):
    return primesfrom2to(num).sum()

def main(flag):
    nums = [70000000,80000000,90000000,100000000,110000000,120000000]
    if flag:
        print('normal:')
        for n in nums:
            print(primesum(n))
    else:
        print('thread:')
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
            for number in executor.map(primesum, nums):
                print(number)
```

Comment: やりたい処理が json ファイルを読んで中身を分解して csv に出力するっていう処理なので numpy でできる処理ではなさそうです。とりあえずスレッドではなくプロセス＋教えていただいたパイプでやろうと思ってます。

Comment: NumPyかどうかではなく … Pythonでの CPUバウンドな処理は GILで遅くなる。I/O バウンドなら大丈夫。CPUバウンドだとしても Pythonそのものではない演算処理 (NumPy含む各種) も大丈夫ということです。
I/Oに占めるウェイトが大きければ Threadでも高速になるかもだけど, ほぼキャッシュで JSON parse部分が大きいようならプロセスがよいかも